# Heroku pgbackups: Syntax errors on localhost restore

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, heroku

Trying to restore database backup made with heroku pgbackups -tool.

I download backup by exposing url:

```
$ heroku pgbackups:url 'backup-name'
```

Created db with:

```
$ createdb 'dbname' -U postgres
```

And tried to restore from *.dump file:

```
$ psql -U postgres -d 'dbname' -f *.dump
```

I end up with following kind of syntax errors:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "PGDMP"
...
ERROR:  invalid byte sequence for encoding "UTF8": 0x9d
HINT:  This error can also happen if the byte sequence does not match the encoding expected by the server, which is controlled by "client_encoding"
```

Ok, so this has something to do with encoding - but how I solve it?

Both config/application.rb and my postgres server has encoding set to UTF-8. database.yml has sqlite configured to it(haven't touched on production config). Gemfile has simply:

```
gem 'pg'
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

I found the answer [directly from the manual](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export):

```
$ curl -o latest.dump `heroku pgbackups:url`

$ pg_restore --verbose --clean --no-acl --no-owner -h myhost -U myuser -d mydb latest.dump
```